# PHP displaying data from four tables in one query (ie: LEFT JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, left-join

I have three tables:
[image: Database tables]

I want to display 'Event Details' which shows attending employee details (listo f employee ids from the 'attending_employees table > corresponding employee details form 'employee' table), what team they belong to (from the club_teams table) and the event details from the 'club_events' table).

Currently I am using multiple mysqli queries to display this information however cannot get my head around pulling the data from the database in one query (ie: LEFT JOIN). Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Below are the queries i am currently using:

```
$query = msqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM attending_employees")or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($attending = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        foreach($attending['club_event']){
            $eventid = $attending['club_event'];
            $query = msqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM club_events WHERE club_event_id = '$eventid'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while($event_details = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                // Echo event details
            }
        }foreach($attending['employee']){
            $empid = $attending['employee'];
            $query = msqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id = '$empid'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while($event_employees = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                // Echo employee details
            }
        }foreach($attending['team']){
            $teamid = $attending['team'];
            $query = msqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM club_teams WHERE clb_team_id = '$teamid'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while($event_team = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                // Echo team details
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method is highly inefficient and wasteful since its retrieving duplicate data (ie: all repeated 'club_event_id's in the 'attending_employees' table.)

Comment: Do you have a draft of a join you've so far experimented with?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont. I tried an 'INNER JOIN' query before however I discarded the code since it didn't return any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = msqli_query(
    $con, 
    "SELECT"
    . " attending_employees.*"
    . ", club_events.*"
    . ", employees.*"
    . ", club_teams.*"
    . " FROM"
    . " attending_employees"
    . " LEFT JOIN club_events ON club_events.club_event_id = attending_employees.club_event"
    . " LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.employee_id = attending_employees.employee"
    . " LEFT JOIN club_teams ON club_teams.clb_team_id = attending_employees.team"
    ) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Is there anyway for me to stop the return of duplicate records. Or should i form an 'IF statement' to avoid echoing out the same event multiple times for when more than one employee takes part in it?